# having trouble with contains method

Tags: java, string, loops, contains

im having trouble with the contains java method inside a while loop this is what my code looks like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)
String s = "";
int moveOn = 0;
while (moveOn == 0) {
            if (s.equals("")){
                System.out.println("blah 1");
                System.out.print("> ");
                s = input.next();
                System.out.println();
            }
            else if (s.contains("something") ||
                     s.contains("something else")) {
                System.out.println("blah 2");
                moveOn++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("blah 3");
                s = "";
            }
}
moveOn = 0;

System.out.println(s + " <- s test");
```

I am trying to make a simple cmd line text game. if you put in *"something"* at the prompt then it works and if you put an input that doesn't have *"something"* or *"something else"* it works as expected. but if you input *"blah blah something"* it will output

```
blah 1
> blah blah something

blah 3
blah 1
> 
blah 3
blah 1
> 
blah 2
something <- s test
```

im pretty sure based on that behavior that it's something with the contains method that I don't understand. I'm sure it's something simple, but does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` returns the next token, and the default separator of tokens is the white space, so the resulting value for the input `blah blah something` is `blah`.

Also, your `moveOn` variable should be a boolean.

Comment: ok, that makes sense thank you! how would you suggest reading the entire line?

Comment: Read the javadoc. You should have it bookmarked and read it as soon as you ask yourself such a question. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29

Comment: whoa wtf I looked and did not see that nextLine method. Wow I'm tired thnx for the help! blah, silly fix I should know better.